# How do I get Java to recognize variables declared inside a try block?

Tags: java, text, encryption

I am making an encryption project which I have working for the most part.  I am reading the plaintext in from a file and encrypting it then writing it to another text file.  I have the same thing for decryption.  I have this working but I am getting a bit confused with the try and catch methods for reading and writing to files. I have two try and catches in one method and the second try method is not recognizing my "decrypted" variable.  How should I deal with this? Here is my code:

```
public static void decrypt(String pathname)
{
  File file = new File(pathname);
  Scanner input = null;
  try
  {
     input = new Scanner(file);
     String tempEncrypted = input.nextLine();
     StringBuffer encrypted = new StringBuffer(tempEncrypted);

     StringBuffer decrypted = new StringBuffer("");
     int shiftAmount = (int)encrypted.charAt(0);

     for(int i = 1; i < encrypted.length(); i++)
     {
        int decChar = ((int)encrypted.charAt(i) - shiftAmount);
        while((int)decChar < 32)
        {
           decChar+=95;
        }
        decrypted.append((char)decChar);
     }
  }
  catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
  {
     System.out.println("*** Cannot open " + pathname + " ***");
     System.exit(1);
  }
  try {
     BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("decrypted.txt"));
     for(int j = 0; j < decrypted.length(); j++)
     {
        out.write(decrypted.charAt(j));
     }
     out.close();
  } 
  catch (IOException e) {}


}
```

Thanks and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How would I fix this then?  Can try take parameters?

Comment: Move the variable declaration to the appropriate scope.  ("Scope" means enclosing `{}` brackets.)

Comment: Also, it is a try *block*, not "try method".

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the point of a try/catch block.  If the exception is thrown, then an error has occurred.  *You don't want to retrieve information from inside a failed try block*.

Instead, simply combine your try blocks into one try/catch, as follows:

```
public static void decrypt(String pathname)
{
  File file = new File(pathname);
  Scanner input = null;
  try
  {
     input = new Scanner(file);
     String tempEncrypted = input.nextLine();
     StringBuffer encrypted = new StringBuffer(tempEncrypted);

     StringBuffer decrypted = new StringBuffer("");
     int shiftAmount = (int)encrypted.charAt(0);

     for(int i = 1; i < encrypted.length(); i++)
     {
        int decChar = ((int)encrypted.charAt(i) - shiftAmount);
        while((int)decChar < 32)
        {
           decChar+=95;
        }
        decrypted.append((char)decChar);
     }

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("decrypted.txt"));
    for(int j = 0; j < decrypted.length(); j++)
    {
       out.write(decrypted.charAt(j));
    }
    out.close();
  }
  catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
  {
     System.out.println("*** Cannot open " + pathname + " ***");
     System.exit(1);
  }
  catch (IOException e) {}

}
```

Comment: But if one might want to see data collected inside the try block once it's been successfully exited.  *All* values that are set inside a try block and one hopes to access outside the block must be declared *and initialized* prior to entering the block.

Comment: Agree entirely, +1 @HotLicks I suggest that 'code following a catch block' is inherently an anti-pattern. There are times to do it but it is inherently problematic and should be viewed with suspicion.

Comment: I agree with both of you that there are times when that is appropriate.  But those times are rare, and this is not one of them.

Comment: @EJP - There's absolutely nothing "anti-pattern" about code following (and outside of) a try/catch.  I've done it many times.  In general, a try/catch should only span the code it's "protecting".

Answer (score 1):

The `decrypted` variable is out of the second `try`'s scope. To make it visible there, you can declare it and initialize it outside of the first `try` block, where you declare your `Scanner` object and the `file`.

```
File file = new File(pathname);
Scanner input = null;
StringBuffer decrypted = new StringBuffer("");
...
```

Comment: Declare *and initialize* outside the block.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with variable scope. The second try/catch block is agnostic of any variables that are created in the first. As soon as the first try/catch block finishes the variable is lost.

If you need that variable to be visible in the second one, you have to initialize it before the first try  and then set the value in the try block. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
void myMethod() {
    try {
        SomeClass x = someValue;
    }
    catch(..) {..}

    SomeClass y = x;
}
```

The compiler will (rightfully) complain that `x` is not defined in that final assignment statement, because `x` was declared inside the `{}` brackets of the `try` and that declaration cannot "escape" from the "scope" defined by the `{}`.

If you instead have

```
void myMethod() {
    SomeClass x;
    try {
        x = someValue;
    }
    catch(..) {..}

    SomeClass y = x;
}
```

The compiler will now complain that the value of `x` is not set in the final assignment statement.  This is because there is no guarantee that the statements inside the `try` range were executed.  (The same would hold if you replaced `try` with `if (some condition)`, and did not also set `x` in the `else` leg.)

But if you have

```
void myMethod() {
    SomeClass x = null;
    try {
        x = someValue;
    }
    catch(..) {..}

    SomeClass y = x;
}
```

The compiler will be (reasonably) happy, since `x` is "visible" in the scope of the final assignment statement, and it's also known to have had a value assigned along all possible paths from it's declaration point to the place where its used.

Answer (score 0):

If a variable is declared inside a block of code, its scope is limited to that block only. You are declaring `decrypted` inside a try / catch block, therefore outside of the block, `decrypted` is no longer available. You can fix this by moving the declaration of `decrypted` in front of the try / catch block and keeping inside only the assignment.

```
StringBuffer encrypted = new StringBuffer();
StringBuffer decrypted = new StringBuffer();

try {
 input = new Scanner(file);
 String tempEncrypted = input.nextLine();
 encrypted = new StringBuffer(tempEncrypted);
 decrypted = new StringBuffer("");
 int shiftAmount = (int)encrypted.charAt(0);

 ...
```

Comment: This makes sense but I want the changed value of decrypted that occurs in the first try block to be available in the second try block.

Comment: @skateboard34: What about this code suggests that wouldn't be the case here?

Comment: That is not a problem, even though declared outside of the try / catch block, the changes in the block are universal, as the variable is handled by reference.

Comment: But `decrypted` must be initialized outside the block, at least to `null`, in order to be accessible outside the block.